# No such module – ARVideoKit

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

[Here is a screen shot of my Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz3At.png) I am trying to work with the ARVideoKit Pod but when I import it  to `appDelegate` it doesn't show any error as soon as I import it to `ViewController` it shows up error "No Such Module" or "Could not build Objective-C module 'ARVideoKit" I tried many things but some times it shows header not found these three error one goes other show's up.

Things I did are the following :

Clean build deleted entire project and rebuild and added pods updated them. Under the build settings in frame work search path i added $(SRCROOT) set it to recursive.

Comment: Try building the project

Comment: did it more than 50 times i guess no luck